# a dynamic list in a GridView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, layout, xamarin.forms, grid

I need to do a GridView that receives a list that I don't know and shows it. How can I do that in xamarin forms?
I need that the layout be repeted like I want, like a template in ListView...In ListView I know How do that but in Grid I don't.
Isn't there a way to set a ListView appearance to Grid the data?
I won't know how many rows and columns it will have, because it dependes of the data quantity.

---

My code behind is:

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CategoriasView : ContentPage
{
    List<Categorias> lstCategorias;
    public CategoriasView()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        CallingCategoriasAsync();

    }

    void eteste()
    {
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        foreach (var item in lstCategorias)
        {
            gridteste.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.nome }, row, column);
            if (column == 0)
            {
                column = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                column = 0;
                row++;
            }

        }
        var i = 0;
    }

    async Task CallingCategoriasAsync()
    {
        lstCategorias = await Webservice.GetCategoriasAsync("1242");
        eteste();

    }
}
```

}

My XAML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="neoFly_Montana.Views.CategoriasView">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>

            <Grid x:Name="gridteste">
            </Grid>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The behind was working when I debbuged it, but nothing is shown on the screen...I think I need to put somenthing in code...

Comment: The Grid and the ListView are two distinct kind of views, you know that, right? Grid is a layout and the listview is a ui component... Can you please explain better your scenario?

Comment: Yeah, I know...but, if I am sure, I can say to a RecycleView if I want it be a grid or a list.
My case is: I will receive a List of data that I don't know How many items it will have and I need set it in a Grid with a Defined layout for each item.

Comment: I got it. I didn't know you was speaking about RecyclerView. So may some like this -> https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/

Comment: Sounds like you need to populate the GridView programmatically: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/

Comment: hmmmm
But When I do that, I need to define the number of rows and columns, don't I?
Thank you !

Comment: @JoycedeLanna You don't. You just need to add views like `myGrid.Children.Add(myLabel, row, col); myGrid.Children.Add(myButton, row, col + 1);`... You can also define a template using a grid in a liestview xaml and get rid of all this verbosity

Comment: Thank you very much I am trying that!

Comment: Show us how looks like your grid layout. Maybe we can help =)

Comment: now it has nothin lol
But I am trying to do like u said and if it doesnt work I show you
Sorry for my english

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza
I changed my question...now, my code is there ...can you help me, please??
(Your name looks like the brazilian names...)

Comment: It's because I'm =). I'm not so good with english as well, be cool. About your code, I guess I can handle it. I'll answer this with the code you need. Wait a minute, please

Comment: haha I was sure you are.
thank u very much !

Comment: The problem was the grid was inside a listview hahahah
Im crazy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150745/discussion-between-diego-rafael-souza-and-joyce-de-lanna).

Comment: how can i define a template for its items?

Answer (score 0):

//Creting a Dynamic Lable

```
Label lbl_new = new Label();  
lbl_new.Text="LablelText";
```

//assigning Row and column Position

```
Grid.SetRow(lbl_new , RowNo);
Grid.SetColumn(lbl_new , ColNo);
```

//Assigning Control to Grid

```
gridteste.Children.Add(lbl_new);
```